# Get a refreshing list of running specific processes

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ps, watch

I want to monitor running python processes with `VSZ, RSS %MEM, %CPU` etc. One of my priorities is  a list refreshing every X seconds. I managed to come to the point of obtaining a refreshing list of processes using `ps` and `watch`

```
ps ax | grep python | awk '{print $1}' | xargs watch -n 15 ps u -p
```

That command simply find all the processes which includes `python` in its command line in `ps` and pass the `pid` values to `watch`.

```
ps u -p 9221 10186 11640 12347 14076 14263 14317 19029 22099 24278 26161 32469
```

It is all fine, but that command evaluates the pid list only once and keep watching those `pid`s. What I need is executing `ps ax | grep python` command every X seconds and get a fresh list of running processes. That Way, I can see which process has started and which one had finished executing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can watch any command so give this a try

`watch "ps aux | grep python"`

Comment: That command do not list all the processes, but only (this is my guess) the ones that are started on current session. I want to watch port listening python processes and some of the are running for weeks.

Comment: Then use `watch "ps aux | grep python"`

Comment: The point is getting the list of PIDs is not needed, you can just watch the output of a greped ps.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use top instead of watch:

```
top -p $(ps ax | grep python | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd "," -) -d 2
```

Comment: That was a great way too, but is it possible to see the process command line since I can only see that it is a python process but can not understand

Comment: Yes you can: add -c option to end of line like: `top -p ... -d 2 -c`

Comment: Ah, that is excellent (: